# kubernetes restricted access to dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I want to create a service account that has a restricted access only.

Let us say I have `namespace` called **devops**

I want to create a `service account` that only access devops and do something which i set in the below role.

```
 kubectl create clusterrole devops-dash-role --verb=get,list --resource=pods --namespace=devops
```

*There i only want the service account to be accessible to that namespace only on that resource*.

then here is my `service account`

```
kubectl create serviceaccount devops-dash-sa -namespace devops
```

Here how i bind them

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding devops-dash-rb --clusterrole=devops-dash-role --serviceaccount=devops:devops-dash-sa
```

then here is how i get the token.

```
kubectl describe secret devops-dash-sa-token-spnpm -n devops
```

then extract the token there.

but once logging into the dashboard it shows nothing.. also it defaulted to `default` namespace.

[image]

Also, I was able to create my own user with my own `kubeconfig` file which I use (as it has restriction) but upon my research that user needs a token as well so I ended up creating service account instead.

Updated:
tried this below commands

```
kubectl create role devops-admin-role --verb="*" --resource="*" --namespace=devops
kubectl create serviceaccount devops-admin-sa --namespace devops
kubectl create rolebinding devops-admin-role-sa-rb --clusterrole=devops-admin-role --serviceaccount=devops:devops-admin-sa
```

but when trying to execute this `kubectl --as system:serviceaccount:devops:devops-admin-sa  get po -n devops`

this is giving me an error : `Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:devops:devops-admin-sa" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "devops"`

Comment: What do you mean by `I only want the service account to be accessible to that namespace only on that resource.` ? And also notice that ClusterRoles/ClusterRoleBinding are NOT namespaced. Use Role/RoleBinding for namespaced permissions.

Comment: i just want to restrict access to the dashboard.. let us say i have namespace ```A``` i want a service account that can only acccess to the dashboard under that namespace

Answer (score 0):

Role:

```
kubectl create role devops-dash-role --verb=get,list --resource=pods --namespace=devops
```

Service account

```
kubectl create serviceaccount devops-dash-sa --namespace devops
```

Role binding:

```
kubectl create rolebinding devops-dash-rb --clusterrole=devops-dash-role --serviceaccount=devops:devops-dash-sa --namespace devops
```

That is all you need.

---

You can also use:

```
--verb="*" --resource="*"
```

to give access to all resources, and because roles and rolebindings are namespaced these permissions will be granted only within the namespace they exist.

Now lets try it:

```
# default namespace
$ kubectl --as system:serviceaccount:devops:devops-dash-sa  get po
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:devops:devops-dash-sa" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

# devops namespace
$ k --as system:serviceaccount:devops:devops-dash-sa  get po -n devops
No resources found in devops namespace
```

When you use it in a dashboard it should work the same.

Comment: Then for accessing the dashboard.. i'll just have to get the token associated with the secret under that service account?

Comment: thnx i'll try that :)

Comment: Let me know if you encounter any problems ;D

Comment: I'll update my post for the result. So that you could view better

Comment: The result is in my original post now Ctrl + F = Updated: tried this below commands
@HelloWorld

Comment: @JaysonGonzaga Oh sorry, The rolebinding is missing --namespace=devops, I corrected it